# Robot Framework How to input text to div javascript

Tags: robotframework, selenium2library

< div class="ace_content" transform: translate(0px, 0px); width: 384px; height: 312px;">

**I Try This**

Input Text....//*[@id="content"]/div[2]/div....testValue

xpath=//*[@id="content"]/div[2]/div

fullxpath=/html/body/div/div/main/div[6]/div/div/form/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div

JS path = document.querySelector("#content > div.ace_scroller > div")